# addToBackStack behaves oddly with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I click an item, it opens a new fragment. When I click back, it returns, but keeps the new fragment visible. Second click on item opens a new fragment. Click back again, and it returns to the first opened fragment. Click back again closes the app.

See this video for a visual explenation: [Screen Capture](http://videobam.com/RTUxg)

Main Activity: `

```
package com.example.exempelfragmentsgrund;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MenyFragment.onMenyKnappClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
System.out.println("MainActivity onCreate");
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_liten) != null){
System.out.println("Detta är den lilla layouten!");                   
                        if (savedInstanceState != null){
                                return;
                        }

                        MenyFragment menyFragment = new MenyFragment();
                        menyFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, menyFragment).commit();
                }
                if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_liten) == null){
System.out.println("Detta är den Stora layouten");
                }
        }

        public void onMenyKnappVald (int position){
System.out.println("MainActivity onMenyKnappVald");

        VisaFragment visaFrag = (VisaFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_dold);

        if (visaFrag != null) {
                visaFrag.visaFragmentArgument(position);

        }else{
                VisaFragment nyttFragment = new VisaFragment();
                Bundle argument = new Bundle ();

                argument.putInt(VisaFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
                nyttFragment.setArguments(argument);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nyttFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        }


        }

}
```

`

Comment: try to remove commit() method

Comment: I have to have commit() when using transaction.replace. If I remove it, the button doesnt' do anyting